# Replace link with another link web browser plugin

Tags: web-browser, plug-in, url

I am visiting a webpage through a proxy it looks like something liek this

https://www.proxy.x.y.com/proxy.ashx?https://www.realwebsite.com/a/b/service?token=HHXG723

Where the real url is `https://www.realwebsite.com/a/b/service`

This is no issue but when looking at the page through the proxy every link is through the original website and not proxified so a link that to say `service/test?a=1`

shows up in the browser as `https://www.realwebsite.com/a/b/service/test?a=1`
and what I need it to show up as is

https://www.proxy.x.y.com/proxy.ashx?https://www.realwebsite.com/a/b/service/test?a=1&token=HHXG723

I know regex so just having something that would allow me to regex href attributes or even the html itself would suffice.

I am open to something for other browsers (IE, FF, etc) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most proxy services do this automatically.  If yours does not, I would suggest changing your proxy service instead of installing a plugin to make that one less bad.